# Amazon EC2 micro instance not responsive to 'which python' command

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I just created my micro ec2 instance and was successful in downloading anaconda. I typed the 'which python' command expecting the ec2 to give me a directory as output but I received nothing. Has anyone experienced this issue before? Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: It seems your distribution is not providing python. You should install it manually or check `python --version` if its installed or not.
Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux-python.html

Comment: I did verify whether I had python installed, it seemed to be just a minor bug which was fixed after I let the instance run a bit longer

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that after some time the 'which python' command started working.

The newly created instance probably just needed some time to load everything. Thanks.